# averaging specific values in a row

Tags: excel

I'm fairly inexperienced with excel so this might be a bit of a basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I have several rows, one is an "index" row while the others contain values. I want to get the averages for each row based on the indexes (average for each index).

I've been looking at the IF function inside an AVERAGE function but I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax so I'm wondering if it is even possible?

I attempted to do it like so for a single average: `=AVERAGE(IF(A3:J3=0;A5:M5;0))`.

Straight away I can see a couple of problems. First for each positive conditional I am saying to use the entire row (I don't know how to map one row to another) as a result. Secondly for each negative conditional I provide a 0 rather than ignoring that value.

From where I'm standing it doesn't seem like what I need is possible to do...am I correct?

Comment: Omit the final zero and your formula is valid....but it's an "array formula" so needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, i.e. `=AVERAGE(IF(A3:J3=0;A5:M5))` - If you are using Excel 2007 or later version, though, AVERAGEIF is better......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF` functions to get the average:

```
=SUMIF(A1:K1,1,A2:K2) / COUNTIF(A1:K1, 1)
```

would give the average you want for index 1 (in row 1, columns A through K), values in row 2.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `AVERAGEIF` function. Something like

```
=AVERAGEIF(A$1:K$1,1,$A2:$K2)
```

should do what you want.