# Excel: Averaging the values from a set of rows, but only include them if they have a specific value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I'm looking for help dynamically averaging the column values of every item in an Excel table that has a given value in one of its columns. Specifically:

I have an Excel sheet where each row represents an entity in a video game I am working on, and each column is a numerical value for different attributes on these entities. Movement Speed, Health, Attack Damage, etc. Each of these rows also has a column where I tag the row with the name of the class that this entity is a part of: "tank", "support", etc. This table has roughly a hundred items in it, and is likely to grow to two or three times that size.

It looks something like this:

[image]

What I would really like to do is have, on a separate tab, a table where each row represents one of the classes, and shows the average value of all of the entities that have that class in their "group" column. And I want it to automatically include new entities of that class as they are added to the first table.

It would look something like this, where these values are automatically generated from the data in the first table (I have no problem manually entering the class names, I just need the numerical data to be driven):

[image]

I imagine that the solution will be a complex, nested pile of `VLOOKUP`s and `MATCH`es and other Excel functions, but I am not really sure how to accomplish this. I didn't even know the proper terminology to search for existing answers to this question, so I hope that it isn't too redundant. Thanks very much for any advice you have!

Version: I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: This question may be the information I need already. Investigating now. I'll update this question if it turns out to be the answer I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670843/averaging-specific-values-in-a-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is a pivot table. (its been around since the 90s?) - and very useful!
there are lots of ways of refreshing etc depending on where the data comes from

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I never knew about these pivot tables. I've been using excel for years! My data isn't structured for it yet, but it looks like it will be worth reorganizing it for this. Thanks!